# Eschew advanced reconcile in P4V

Tags: perforce, p4v

When I try to reconcile, I'm sometimes interrupted by this alert. How can I just do a normal reconcile?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cVLHh.png]

Also sometimes I see this same alert when I'm trying to *cancel* a reconcile. Why doesn't P4V take me straight back to the main window?

Answer (score 1):

Direct Answer: Normally you can ignore that popup by clicking on cancel. It will do an "un-Advanced" reconcile. But behavior may depend on your client/server versions...

This page http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Managing_lost_connection.html describes "Advanced Reconcile" as an "optional" step, but does not explain wtf (why the f) they had to add it.

I never had a problem with the reconcile before they introduced Advanced, but now it seems that a reconcile can fail to actually reconcile everything and you need to do an advanced reconcile to get the files it missed.

Lesson learned... After a "normal" reconcile (by click on "Cancel" the first time), do the reconcile again and select advanced (which does a folder diff), it shouldn't produce anything, but if it does, then you need to review those files.

Comment: Also wrt what it does, the link provides that info: A folder diff of the local folder vs depot, which is basically what is expected of reconcile functionality without having to call it "Advanced"!-P

Answer (score 0):

Can you post an example of what the 'Advanced Reconcile' dialog looks like when you bring it up?  That'll help diagnose why the basic reconcile doesn't work.  As one example, if you tell P4V you're going to add a file, then delete it from disk, the basic reconcile doesn't work.

FWIW, I usually drop to the command line and run `p4 reconcile` as a faster option.